# Firefox developer edition TypeError

Tags: firefox, web, development-environment, web-deployment, firefox-developer-tools

Just have installed new firefox developer edition and one of the feautures is checking the website in another browsers remotely. So I opened my website and typed in firefox's new command line "ios" to test it on safary, but got error `TypeError: response is null`   .

Did somebody already tried? Any ideas how to make this work? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [list of connection issues here](https://github.com/campd/fxdt-adapters/labels/connection) and you can [submit a new issue here](https://github.com/campd/fxdt-adapters/issues/new) if it is not listed.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Valence addon (the thing that makes connecting to ios and chrome possible) everyday without any problem, but I always go via the WebIDE. I never tried using the ios command. I'm not sure how much this command was tested recently, it might just be broken.

You should try using the WebIDE (which you can find in the Tools/Web Developer menu).
Once opened, you can select "Safari on iOS" from the runtime menu.

[More information about this can be found on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Valence).

I've filed [the following issue on the Github repo](https://github.com/campd/fxdt-adapters/issues/113). Feel free to comment on the issue to add more info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've just released 0.2.3 of the Valence (Developer Tools Adapter) add-on.  Once you get this update, the `ios` command should work as expected.  You can check your current version on the `about:addons` page.

If you continue to have trouble, please file a [new issue](https://github.com/campd/fxdt-adapters/issues/new).